# Finding max value of each column of 4x4 Array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following array in both `MatrixForm` and `List` form

```
0.474042    0.507508    0.4977      0.539773

0.473447    0.50765     0.483809    0.52489

0.46797     0.483669    0.494823    0.516956

0.467079    0.483509    0.478704    0.501286


A = {{ 0.474042, 0.507508, 0.4977,   0.539773},
     { 0.473447, 0.50765,  0.483809, 0.52489 },
     { 0.46797,  0.483669, 0.494823, 0.516956},
     { 0.467079, 0.483509, 0.478704, 0.501286}
    }
```

I want to get the max value of each column. I've tried the following for the first columns but no help:

```
Max[A[[All, 1]]]
```

Any comment will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Max/@Transpose@A ?

Comment: Well actually using `Max[]` on each column does the trick. Your syntax is correct for the first column.

Comment: I am getting weird result though. Here it's:
Max[0.467079,0.46797,0.473447,0.474042]

Any recommendation?

Comment: @UTK that seems very strange as that should evaluate to `0.474042` automatically. Does `Definition[Max]` have anything more than just `Attributes[Max]=...`? If it does you can restart the kernel to reset all definitions you have made. (In the menu Evaluation->Quit kernel->Local)

Comment: Is it possible you have "strings" in A? Does `A[[1,1]]//FullForm` have " around the value?

Comment: I do have strings in A and A[[1,1]] does not give me a value.

Comment: Use `ToExpression` to to convert the strings into numbers, `A=ToExpression[A]`

Answer (score 2):

As already recommended by belisarius but once again as complete code to leave no stone unturned:

```
A = {{0.474042, 0.507508, 0.4977, 0.539773}, {0.473447, 0.50765, 0.483809, 
    0.52489}, {0.46797, 0.483669, 0.494823, 0.516956}, {0.467079, 0.483509, 0.478704, 
    0.501286}};

A // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0.474042 & 0.507508 & 0.4977 & 0.539773 \\
 0.473447 & 0.50765 & 0.483809 & 0.52489 \\
 0.46797 & 0.483669 & 0.494823 & 0.516956 \\
 0.467079 & 0.483509 & 0.478704 & 0.501286
\end{array}
\right)$

```
Max /@ Transpose[A]
```

> ```
> {0.474042, 0.50765, 0.4977, 0.539773}
> ```

Also less efficiently:

```
MapThread[Max, A]
```

> ```
> {0.474042, 0.50765, 0.4977, 0.539773}
> ```

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.I have tried all of the methods that you mentioned here but for some reasons it is not working yet. I have a huge code and this matrix is in a for loop. Do you think reason might be the for loop ? I can share the part of my code if you think it helps. But it's so weird that it's not working in this code but works in other examples.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you all.

Comment: @UTK I'm glad you have a solution but I'm curious: what was the problem?  Did you have a table of Strings as ssch suggested?

Answer (score 1):

```
A = { {0.474042,0.507508,0.4977,0.539773},  {0.473447,0.50765,0.483809,0.52489},
     {0.46797,0.483669,0.494823,0.516956}, {0.467079,0.483509,0.478704,0.501286}}
```

Try

```
Max @ A[[All, #]] & /@ Range[4]
```

Which gives:

> `{0.474042, 0.50765, 0.4977, 0.539773}`

You can also do:

```
Max @@@ (A\[Transpose])
```

Comment: Well, for some reasons I am getting the following:
{Max[0.467079,0.46797,0.473447,0.474042],
Max[0.483509,0.483669,0.507508,0.50765],
Max[0.478704,0.483809,0.494823,0.4977],
Max[0.501286,0.516956,0.52489,0.539773]}

Any idea?

Comment: Did you include the ampersand? I can't  reproduce your result. Maybe start a new *Mathematica* session.

Comment: Obviously Max does not evaluate. Restart the kernel as mentioned above.